# Working with delegates and encapsulation/ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, swift

So I created a delegate in the following way:

```
class MessengerTableViewController: UITableViewController, MessengerTableViewControllerDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

//..Insert Various functions Here..

func messengerScrollToBottom() {

        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX), animated: true)
    }
}
```

The protocol is :

```
protocol MessengerTableViewControllerDelegate {
    func messengerScrollToBottom()
}
```

And the class using messengerScrollToBottom() is the superView :

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var containerViewController : UIView

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.msgDelegate = MessengerTableViewController(coder: nil)
    }

   func keyboardWillShow(aNotification: NSNotification)    {

    self.msgDelegate!.messengerScrollToBottom()
   }
}
```

This will not work because within the `ContainerViewController init()` function, `msgDelegate` is not assigned to the proper `MessageTableViewController`. It does not point to the `MessengerTableViewController` that is already created by the storyboard in memory. Therefore the code executes fine, however I see no change in the tableView onscreen. My question is, how can I modify this code to have it occur as intended?

**Here is an image of my storyboard:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyl9J.jpg

Help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController ].
        if segue?.identifier == "tableView" {

            let child = segue!.destinationViewController as? MessengerTableViewController

            self.msgDelegate = child
        }
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
```

I implemented the code above and now it works..except with one catch. The tableView is blank upon executing `messengerScrollToBottom()` . Any know why?

Second edit: Turns out CGFLOAT_MAX was the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate when you segue to the MessengerTableViewController. Since you're using a segue, you should do that in prepareForSegue. Get a reference to the MessengerTableViewController with segue.destinationViewController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

     let messengerTVC: MessengerTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
     self.msgDelegate = messengerTVC;   
}
```

Comment: Please look at question and let me know why you think the tableView becomes blank white.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try declaring a `MessageTableViewController` property in your header file, and then bind it to the `MessageTableViewController` in your storyboard?  Then in the `init()` you could assign that property to be the object's delegate?

Comment: in header file:
`@property (strong) IBOutlet MessageTableViewController* messageTable;`

then use the assistant editor to bind the `messageTable` property to the `MessageTableViewController` in your xib file.

Lastly, in your implementation file init() method, set `self.delegate = _messageTable`